# PHP undefined mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm checking the database if a username is taken, but I keep getting this error "Call to undefined function mysqli_result() on line 9.

```
<?
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
  if (!empty($username)){
    $username_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT ('id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'");
    $username_result = mysqli_result($username_query, 0);

    if ($username_result == 0){
        echo 'Available.';
        } else if($username_result == 1){
        echo 'Username unavailable.';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Perhaps because I'm using jQuery to handle the input from a different file and checking it with this, it's saying that it's undefined. This same code works fine in the tutorial that I'm watching, but he is using mysql instead of mysqli.
Edit: The fixed code looks like replaces $username_query and $username_rsult -

```
    $data = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(`username`) AS num FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$username."'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    $numUsers = $row['num'];
if ($numUsers >= 1){
        echo 'That user already exists.';
    }else{
        echo 'Username is available.';
    }
```

Comment: Why not use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this because forgetting to escape one value is enough to leave a gigantic [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) in your application.

Comment: That function doesn't exist, [read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) - you seem to be mixing the procedural and object sides of mysqli (mysqli_result is part of the object interface).  But **do read** the advice the others are giving.

Comment: [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) is a class, not a function. After you've called [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), you can iterate through the result set using functions such as [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other functions of the [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class that you should use, e.g. `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Said that, it's better to use prepared statements to bind and retrieve data, e.g.

```
$_stmt = $_mysqli->prepare('SELECT `permissies` FROM `gebruiker` WHERE (`id`=? AND `pwdenc`=?)');
$_stmt->bind_param('is', $_cred[0], $_cred[1]);
$_stmt->execute();
$_stmt->bind_result($perm);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I forgot that I already had PHP code with those functions, so I just had to replace the tutorial's code with that.